Is $\hat{H}^2 = c^2\left(\hat{p}^2+m^2c^2\right)$ valid quantum physics?
From Schrödinger equation we know that $\hat{H}=\hat{E} $ for non-relativistic systems.
For relativistic scenarios we use the usual $\hat{E}^2 = c^2\left(\hat{p}^2+m^2c^2 \right)$. From this we can derive Klein-Gordon and Dirac equations.
Nonetheless, what would happen if we replace $\hat{E}$ with $\hat{H}$? Is that valid physics? The immediate result would be (for a free particle):
$$\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{4m^2c^2}\nabla^4 + \nabla^2 - \frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}\right)\psi = 0$$
Where $\nabla^4$ is the biharmonic operator. I guess this equation does not apply as we would be comparing something classical to something relativistic, but I am curious to know if this is the case and what would the equation represent if not.

I recommend reading chapter 8 of "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by J.J. Sakurai.

what correspondence principle did you use?

@TheTiler what do you mean by correspondence?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle The correspondence between classical values ​​and operators is $E\leftrightarrow i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, $\vec{p} \leftrightarrow -i\hbar \vec{\nabla} $

@TheTiler I used the definition for the momentum operator you just mentioned and the usual $\hat{H} = \hat{p}^2/2m$ for a free particle

@AlmostClueless Read. He uses the Hamiltonian but with the prescription $i\hbar c\partial_{ct}$ rather than $\hat{p}^2/2m$ to get a relativistic wave equation. Yet I’m interesting in what validity has the other prescription, stated in the post.

See :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Already your equation does not depend on time...., in addition in relativity $E-mc^{2}=E_{k}=(\gamma -1)mc^{2}\approx E_{k_{classic}}$

@TheTiler hm. So time is what makes this equation problematic, because a relativistic setup should always include it? Otherwise it is… wrong? Incomplete? Interesting.

Just because I didn't understand it :-)

a first-order equation with respect to time, page 4785 :http://www.sciences.ch/Opera_Magistris_v4_r2_en.pdf

How did you get $\nabla^4$? By plugging non-relativistic $\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{\mathbf p}^2}{2m}$ into relativistic relation $E^2 = c^2\mathbf p^2 + m^2c^4$? Why do such a thing?

We start off with the relativistic square-rooted energy-momentum relation:
$$ \hat{H} = c\sqrt{ m^2 c^2+ \hat{p}^2}$$
For non-relativistic velocities $\hat{p}$ is small, so one can develop the right side of the square-rooted equation:
$$ \hat{H} = mc^2\sqrt{ 1 + \frac{\hat{p}^2}{m^2c^2}} \approx mc^2\left(1 + \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2 m^2c^2}\right) = mc^2 + \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$$
So when you plug in for $\hat{H}$ on the left side not $\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$, but $mc^2 + \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$ because $\hat{H}$, as it is basically relativistic, also includes the energy at rest, then the result turns out to be a trivial identity.
Otherwise, plugging without precaution in a relativistic equation a non-relativistic relation, leads to contradictions.
